# Does const qualifier increases the life time of temporary compound literal?

Tags: c++, gcc

[GNU C++ extension implements compound literal differently form C99](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) in the sense that GNU C++ compound literal is a temporary object and has single-line life time.

So this code gives compile error trying to get the address of such a temporary object:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <valarray>

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    std::valarray<int> arr((int[]){1,1,2,2,3}, n);
                          //^^^^^ error here, although the compound literal 
                          // outlives the constructor
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

However, by changing `(int[]){1,1,2,2,3}` to `(const int[]){1,1,2,2,3}`, this error disappears and the code [runs OK](http://ideone.com/cyMzZu).

Then it seems that by adding `const` qualifier the compound literal's is no longer a temporary.

I know that `const` reference can increase the life time of temporary object to the life time of the reference, but I don't see how that is related to this question.

So my question is, is above code well defined behavior by C++ standard and/or GNU C++ extension?

Comment: I wonder what the error message says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a GCC extension, it certainly cannot be defined by the C++ standard. As far as the standard goes, the program is not well-formed.

The GNU documentation (as per your link) points out that the `const` modifier might change the behaviour:

> As an optimization, the C++ compiler sometimes gives array compound literals longer lifetimes: when the array either appears outside a function or has const-qualified type. If ‘foo’ and its initializer had elements of ‘char *const’ type rather than ‘char *’, or if ‘foo’ were a global variable, the array would have static storage duration.

But goes on to suggest:

> But it is probably safest just to avoid the use of array compound literals in code compiled as C++.

As an aside, since C++11, there is a `std::valarray` constructor taking an `initializer_list`, so the following is well-formed in C++11 without GCC extensions:

```
std::valarray<int> arr{1,1,2,2,3};
```