# Effect of new on lifetime in a compound literal - or on address?

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm trying to use <del>compounds</del> the {} notation of initializer lists for initializing static local constants in C++11.
The question might be a follow-up of [one about temporary arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212114/clang-complains-pointer-is-initialized-by-a-temporary-array).
There may be a side track(?) [hinting at **const**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946080/does-const-qualifier-increases-the-life-time-of-temporary-compound-literal?rq=1) (but only for C99?).
Another question [brings heap allocation into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686729/a-portable-c-alternative-to-compound-literals-that-is-guaranteed-to-be-free-of), but with a difference,
I think.

The idea is for a function to establish a data structure in its own
scope, once. A `static` (const) variable definition takes values from the lists as written (by misguided intention: C-style
compound literals). Later, the function should be able to refer to the
structure.  The SO links above explain, both directly and indirectly,
why just literals won't work.

Will `new` help, though?

```cpp
int undef()
{
  static const int vs[3] {1,2,3};
  static const int* vss[2] {
    vs,
    // (const int[3]){1,2,3}          // temporary will be lost
    new const int[3] {1,2,3}
  };
  return vss[0][1] + vss[1][1];
}
```

My guess: `new` will allocate an array *somewhere*, initialize the
new array from the temporary `{1,2,3}` and then that *somewhere* continues to have an
address. So, nothing is lost. Correct?

Is the above use of `new` safe and sound, meaning covered by the
standard? C++11 in my case.

Comment: There are no compound literals in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is defined behavior. The only pedantic issue is a technical memory leak. Nothing will ever formally `delete` it, but it'll only be allocated once, and it'll exist for the entire program's execution. Big deal. The only practical annoyance would be static memory sanitizers reporting a "possible" memory leak, from something like this.

Comment: It's exempt from avoiding "naked **new**" then, not a garbage collector around? Good.

Comment: There is no garbage collection in C++.

Comment: ("Garbage collection is optional in C++" (TCPL 4ed, § 34.5). The standard seems to address GC as a possibility, a "garbage-collecting implementation", in Memory > Pointer Safety of §iso.20, for example. But, there is no GC offered by the compilers I use. So I am assuming that it's fine allocating once, like the answer says.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that quote, but garbage collection in the current C++ standard would violate some fairly fundamental core C++ concepts (unless garbage collection is defined simply as "release memory but don't call any destructors). In any care, garbage collection would have no effect here, since a reference to the `new`ed object remains in scope.